# Implications of a normal subgroup with a prime index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose $H$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$ of prime index $p$.

I need to show that for any $K \leq G$ we have either:

1. $K \leq H$ or
2. $G = HK$ and $|K: K \cap H| = p$.

What I've determined so far:

I am able to use the second isomorphism theorem to show that if $G = HK$, then $|K: K \cap H| = p$. This is because we'd have that
$$
G/H = HK/H \simeq K/K\cap H
$$
and we know that $|G/H| = |G:H| = p$ because $H$ is normal, so $|K / K \cap H| = p$.

I can deduce that if $K \leq H$, then $G \neq HK$. This is because if $K \leq H$, then $HK = H < G$.

If $G$ is finite, then I could use Lagrange's Theorem, but it is not guaranteed that $G$ is finite.

So the last thing I really need to prove is that if $K \not\leq H$, then it must be the case that $G = HK$. I've worked through some simple examples and it has held true, but I'm unable to prove that it will *always* be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $H \leq KH \leq G$, and $[G:KH][KH:H]=[G:H]=p$, which is prime.  Since $[KH:H] \gt 1$, the only other possibility is $[KH:H]=p$, which implies $[G:KH]=1$ and $KH=G$.

Comment: That's what I needed, thanks. I forgot that if H is normal, that implies that HK is a subgroup.